# vagrant up fails with sed error message

Tags: vagrant, puppet

Hello my vagrant starts failing boot with this message

The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

sed -e '/^#VAGRANT-BEGIN/,/^#VAGRANT-END/ d' /etc/network/interfaces > /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.

The vagrant boots, but the puppet manifests are not applied.

any suggestions how to fix it

Update: The vagrant up command fails before starting applying puppet manifests.

> INFO interface: info: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
>   [default] Configuring and enabling network interfaces... DEBUG ssh:
>   Checking whether SSH is ready... DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection. 
>   INFO ssh: SSH is ready!  INFO guest: Detect guest for machine:
>
> ## DEBUG guest: Trying: pld DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.  INFO ssh: Execute: cat /etc/pld-release
>
> (sudo=false) DEBUG ssh: stderr: cat: /etc/pld-release DEBUG ssh:
>   stderr: : No such file or directory
>
> DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 1 DEBUG guest: Trying: suse DEBUG ssh:
>   Re-using SSH connection.  INFO ssh: Execute: cat /etc/SuSE-release
>   (sudo=false) DEBUG ssh: stderr: cat: /etc/SuSE-release DEBUG ssh:
>   stderr: : No such file or directory
>
> DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 1 DEBUG guest: Trying: fedora DEBUG ssh:
>   Re-using SSH connection.  INFO ssh: Execute: grep 'Fedora release
>   1[678]' /etc/redhat-release (sudo=false) DEBUG ssh: stderr: grep:
>   /etc/redhat-release DEBUG ssh: stderr: : No such file or directory
>
> DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 2 DEBUG guest: Trying: ubuntu DEBUG ssh:
>   Re-using SSH connection.  INFO ssh: Execute: cat /proc/version | grep
>   'Ubuntu' (sudo=false) DEBUG ssh: stdout: Linux version
>   3.2.0-32-generic (buildd@batsu) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 26 21:33:09 UTC 2012
>
> DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 0  INFO guest: Detected: ubuntu!  INFO guest:
>   Full guest chain: [[:ubuntu,
>
> ## ], [:debian, #], [:linux, #]]  INFO guest: Execute capability: configure_networks (ubuntu) DEBUG guest: Searching for
>
> cap: configure_networks DEBUG guest: Checking in: ubuntu DEBUG guest:
>   Checking in: debian DEBUG guest: Found cap: configure_networks in
>   debian DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.  INFO ssh: Execute: sed -e
>   '/^#VAGRANT-BEGIN/,/^#VAGRANT-END/ d' /etc/network/interfaces >
>   /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces (sudo=true) DEBUG ssh: stderr: sudo:
>   no tty present and no askpass program specified
>
> DEBUG ssh: stderr: Sorry, try again.
>
> DEBUG ssh: stderr: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program
>   specified
>
> DEBUG ssh: stderr: Sorry, try again. sudo: no tty present and no
>   askpass program specified Sorry, try again. sudo: 3 incorrect password
>   attempts
>
> DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 1 ERROR warden: Error occurred: The following
>   SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes
>   that this means the command failed!
>
> sed -e '/^#VAGRANT-BEGIN/,/^#VAGRANT-END/ d' /etc/network/interfaces >
>   /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces

Comment: Have you tried `VAGRANT_LOG=debug vagrant up` and see more output? What kind of Puppet manifests are you running, better put them in the question.

Comment: Same error as => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644693/vagrant-does-not-start-correctly-and-not-mount-shared-folders

Answer (score 2):

For me this problem was caused by the vagrant user not being able to run sudo without a password.

Logging in to the guest (through gui mode) and making sure the vagrant user was set up like so in /etc/sudoers was the fix :

```
vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Run 'visudo' as root in order to edit this file.

I actually had extra fun because the .box file was set up correctly, but my puppet manifests overwrote sudoers with other groups - so the initial vagrant up ran fine, but subsequent provisions failed.

Comment: my problem was not as above mentioned. But that did help me in my case where the problem was similar where vagarant cant run command without password.

Answer (score 0):

`vagrant up` is trying to remove any existing blocks like below

```
#VAGRANT-BEGIN
# The contents below are automatically generated by Vagrant. Do not modify.
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
    post-up route del default dev $IFACE
#VAGRANT-END
```

in `/etc/network/interfaces` and inject a new block to enable default NAT networking mode.

`sed -e '/^#VAGRANT-BEGIN/,/^#VAGRANT-END/ d' /etc/network/interfaces > /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces`

The command removes the block generated by vagrant and redirect the output to a new file, it is a part of the `vagrant up` process, I believe. No idea why vagrant complains about a non-zero exit code. Even if there is no such code block, sed should return 0. May be a bug.

> NOTE: Vagrant 1.3.0 has just been released. Try to upgrade your vagrant (1.3.0) + virtualbox (4.2.16) combo to latest versions.

HTH