# Vagrant does not start correctly and not mount shared folders

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

when I do `vagrant up` I get this:

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

sed -e '/^#VAGRANT-BEGIN/,/^#VAGRANT-END/ d' /etc/network/interfaces > /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces
```

And synced folders are not available. How to fix this? I use

```
Linux precise64 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What is your vagrant version and VirtualBox? Please try to upgrade to 1.3 + 4.2.16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `vagrant up`, it'll inject the configuration like below into `/etc/network/interfaces` file to enable default NAT networking mode.

```
#VAGRANT-BEGIN
# The contents below are automatically generated by Vagrant. Do not modify.
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
    post-up route del default dev $IFACE
#VAGRANT-END
```

This command `sed -e '/^#VAGRANT-BEGIN/,/^#VAGRANT-END/ d' /etc/network/interfaces > /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces` removes the block generated by vagrant and redirect the output to a new file. No idea why vagrant complains about a non-zero exit code. Even if there is no such code block, sed should return 0.

Try to enable debug output `VAGRANT_LOG=debug vagrant up` and see if it gives more information.

> NOTE: Vagrant 1.3.0 has just been released. Try to upgrade your vagrant + virtualbox combo to latest versions.

Comment: Updating vagrant (to 1.3.1), using https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest and vagrant reload solved an issue!